# Deploy a Swift OS X app locally?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I am not new to programming, but I am new to Swift. I have developed a small app that I have no intention of distributing, I just want to use it for myself. Everything works just as desired in XCode and now I want to deploy that app locally. How can I run my app on my machine without needing to have XCode also running? I just want to see my app in my Applications folder and run it when I want. Does XCode put build files somewhere that I can access them and use outside of XCode?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit: while this answer still works, it targets old Xcode versions and uses the debug version of your executable. For recent Xcode versions, and for using the release version of your executable, see [JeremyP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35486931/2227743).**

Each time you build an OS X application with the current scheme, Xcode automatically populates the "Products" folder with the related app bundle.

You can find this folder in the Project Navigator:

> Xcode > Project Navigator > "Products" folder

Your `.app` is in there and ready to be used and/or copied to the /Applications folder.

[image]

Comment: Please note that this uses the debug version of the executable. If you want the release version, follow JeremyP's answer.

Answer (score 24):

On the *Product* menu there is an *Archive* option. Select that to create an archive of your app.

Xcode should then automatically open the Organiser window with the archive of your app selected.

You'll see a big blue button called *Upload to App Store* on the right with two smaller buttons below it. The one you want is called *Export...* Press it and you'll get a pane giving you various export options with different kinds of signing.

The bottom option creates an unsigned `.app` file which you can put in your *Applications* directory.

NB As Eric D says, you can just drag the app out of the products directory, but unless you edit the scheme, that will give you a debug build with less optimisation and with asserts activated.

**Update for Xcode 11.2**

As [Bell B. Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4451268/belle-b-cooper) points out, the process has changed slightly. Now when you archive an app, you get a window listing the apps and a big blue "Distribute" button. Pressing this, gets you a dialog box giving you the various options. Which one you choose depends on what you want to do with the executable. With Catalina, unless it's just for your own use, you probably want to go for one of the options that involves signing the app.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to export this archive for those not enrolled in the Apple Developer Program?

Comment: In Xcode 11 the layout has changed a bit. You now need to click on "Distribute", which is the big blue button that used to say "Upload to App Store". That will open a dialog with several choices—the last choice is called "Copy App" and this one exports a copy of the app to a directory of your choice.

Comment: @BelleB.Cooper Yes, this answer is 3.5 years old. I've added an update.